# Learning about security of UART and RS232

Tags: serial, uart, rs232, computers, security

I'm trying to learn about UART and related problems and solutions.

IIUC, UART is a hardware, RS232 is an interface and hyperterminal is a program. Would these parts be able to work together?

I asked a knowledgable professor in CS who illustrated it with an application use case where I understood some but not all.

I attach the illustration of the description where I understand some but not all.

[image]

I want to understand it all. Please correct me if I'm wrong

1. Why is a message-queue relevant? It looks like an array of msg?
2. Why is S (memory size) relevant?
3. Why is the difference between DMA and MMI relevant? Is it because DMA bypasses the CPU and therefore the CPU can't be relied for security?
4. Is ETH ethernet and could be via UART or only UART? Is the hyperterminal and standard i/o and tty examples of UART?

I will read more online sources of course.

K means a key file that should not be accessible and the ethernet connection, IIUC, is example of peripheral connection via UART.

P is supposed to mean a pointer. I vaguely hypothesize that it's about getting a pointer to a part of the RAM that is supposed to be secure.

Can you help me understand?

Comment: The question sounds like a heap of unrelated (or loosely related) terms. What *exactly* you are trying to learn? RS-232 protocol? How it is implemented in UART HW? How to program SW interfacing the UART? And what security has to do with that? These all things of totally different levels of abstraction.

Comment: The use case is supposed to be about whether or not a UART hardware peripheral can access any secret. I think that the example is connecting physically by UART and rs232 and by such means getting unauthorized access. I think that my FPGA Altera DE2 and DE2-115 can be used to try it. One goal is to learn formal model of the hardware and we might choose NuSMV once we know what to model and check. It's a university term project I do.

Comment: I afraid your comment have just added even more noise to the question...

Comment: The diagram looks to be about a NIC (Network Interface Card) connected to Ethernet and absolutely nothing to with RS232 or UARTs. Are you sure about you question?

Comment: I'm supposed to build a formal model of UART and rs232. I'm supposed to do model checking using a tool. I'm supposed to formally verify a security model if connecting via UART and rs232 to a computer system. Maybe that can be compared to connecting via Ethernet and a NIC. The goal is to check that a secret file or some secret bytes such as a key for a cryptography is only accessed by authorized users or inaccessible. I think that could be similar to the "BadUSB" connection but simpler. I do understand parts of it but not everything. I could read more about it and return when I understand more.

Comment: "The goal is to check that a secret file or some secret bytes such as a key for a cryptography is only accessed by authorized users or inaccessible." Ok, then, it has nothing to do with electronics, really. These kind of security measures are implemented in software, either in the OS or in the application. As Eugene said, it seems there is a lot of confusion between all the layers involved, here (and it is rather broad, in addition to being unclear).

Comment: I have doubts really about "that has nothing to do with electronics". What makes you sure that we can just completety ignorera electronics? When physical access is easy to understand it might become a security problem. Physical access is the easiest case of insecure data isn't it? I agree that it's less clear than crystal but not inconceivable that all details are relevant.

Comment: @DacSaunders Only you know what you want to do. None of us commenters seem to understand it yet.

Comment: What is it that you don't exclude? What is it that you exclude? Surely we understand that I can know that I don't know much about the relations between the parts. Some lack of knowledge is easy to understand e.g. Is UART a way of standard i/o and tty or again nothing to do with it that is something also excluded. How could you make conclusions if you didn't understand?

Comment: @DacSaunders Well, I don't know about dim, but *I* don't understand what you need to know. Maybe it's because your question has too many different parts to it and it's not clear where the separation between them is. Can you ask a single clear and specific question?

Comment: @DacSaunders Also you seem to be asking how to interpret this diagram. I don't know, I didn't draw the diagram and it's not any kind of standard diagram.

Comment: Because physical access to a UART will lead to absolutely nothing if no software listens to that port. E.g. take a linux box, kill every process that may potentially listen to /dev/ttyS0. You can plug anything you want on the corresponding port, nothing will happen (unless there is a bug in the kernel, but this part is software too). Physical access to a machine is the easiest way to hack it because there is software listening to the keyboard and the peripherals. Really, if you can hack a machine by plugging something on a port, it is because the software allows it.

Comment: @dim That is not necessarily the case when DMA and hardware bugs involved. Dac is trying to create a "security model" to prove what can and can't be accessed.

Comment: @immibis What is the DMA doing here? If a DMA transfer happens when you plug something on a UART port, it is because the software (kernel) configured the DMA to do so. The DMA doesn't decide to perform transfers randomly by itself.

Comment: @dim "and hardware bugs"

Comment: @immibis Oh, of course. And single-upset events... Well, then, you can't guarantee anything anymore. The worst could happen, and you can't prove it won't happen.

Comment: @immibis Now we got it: _Dac is trying to create a "security model" to prove what can and can't be accessed_ Exactly. I want to learn how I can formalize it. Of course I must understand it first. Then I must know what I don't know. Basics about UART, tty and rs232 I can read about or ask about. If we don't even understand then of course we can't make such confident conclusions: _"That has nothing to do with it."_ And you neither know what that or the other thing is. How can you make confident conclusions if you don't understand? At least I know which parts I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RS232 is an electrical and connector specification for how the voltages are interpreted as 1 or 0, and how they are connected, nothing more.

A UART essentially does the parallel to serial conversion and adds (and strips) some usually fairly minimal amount of framing around the (usually) bytes it sends, its interface to the processor is usually a memory mapped register and an interrupt or polling, DMA as such would be uncommon but possible, uart serial is usually just not that quick. There is nothing that requires either that RS232 be async serial from a UART (But it usually is) or that a UART ultimately drive RS232.

Hyperterminal is a program that can be configured to talk to a serial port, but you cannot assume that is the only attack vector.

The place you will find software vulnerabilities is in the higher levels of whatever protocol you are carrying over the RS232 link, for example you might be carrying TCP/IP encapsulated as SLIP over that link, which is a huge attack surface even if the high level application is something simple. The UART and the dozen or so lines of code that read bytes and stuff them into the rx ring buffer is seldom the problem, it is all the complex stuff that happens afterwards.
Best case, I can convince some of the higher level stuff to crash, possibly the developer has left an assert on with the dump set to the serial port... Game on!

For hardware vulnerabilities, I would be thinking side channel attacks, either looking at noise on the signal lines (Can be used to estimate processor power consumption, which with poorly done crypto can leak key information). 
Possibly I might be able to abuse an input protection diode to force the power supply for the processor out of tolerance, maybe I learn something useful.... 
Maybe I can apply some RF to the serial port and get a crash that way, maybe I apply RF, sense the leakage on the supply wires and find that it is phase modulated in a way that leaks information, lots of things to try.
Been there, done that.

You may find a talk given at 29C3 by Timo entitled "Milking the digital cash cow" interesting (It is on youtube as well as in the CCCs archives) as it demonstrates a side channel attack in the real world.