# Is my illustration of this configuration good enough?

Tags: uart, rs232, linux, homework, peripheral

I do a university project about hardware peripherals. I have little experience with it coming from a computer science background. The project is about connecting a peripheral to the serial UART RS-232 console.

I could easily demo direct root shell if I open the serial UART connection and connect with minicom, then I got a root shell without a password with "the humble shell" hush on busybox/barebox using uClinux.

My illustration is the following.

[image]

Do you agree that my illustration is "good enough" ? I'm going to add Linux on top and then I might think it could get approved by my supervisor. ''

UP means "user process", DR means "driver" and K means "cryptographic key" or some other data that should be protected.

Comment: It lacks too many specifics on capacity, speed and all the other inferfaces like power, reset, IO , memory configuration,

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Those details are unlikely to be relevant to the diagram.

Comment: What is the box labeled "DR" supposed to represent?

Comment: Then at least include all the RS-232 interface signals and which are software controlled internally and expected for a establishing communication even if you decline the option to use flow control or is it just TTL level UART signals?

Comment: You can make it even simpler if you have a target in mind.  http://www.embeddedforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Raspberry-pi-UART-connections-block-diagram.png  A block diagram for physical IO and one for logical functions.

Comment: I agree with @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 that you should rather find a [block diagram](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=block+diagram+linux+uart) showing what you want to communicate.

Comment: Note to other readers: I think it's helpful to give readers here, the links to related previous questions from this OP - "[Learning about security of UART and RS232](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/286769/)" (and, to a lesser extent "[Common way of looking at UART?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/291043/)") to understand the context of this new question, which is for the OP to "formally verify a security model if connecting via UART and rs232 to a computer system [...] The goal is to check that a secret file or some secret bytes [...] is only accessed by authorized users"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UARTS do not in the general scheme of things do DMA, so they do not have direct access to memory in the sense that something like firewire sometimes gives.

The MMU is actually a big deal in all this as it provides the memory protection between processes as well as the memory mappings for the peripheral busses. I would absolutely show it (Possibly as a table with pointers to the processes in memory or something).

Something closer would be the UART communicating with a user process (Via a kernel interrupt handler) which puts the attack surface as being the userspace application (and the kernel console driver) running connected to the UART in the first instance, then possibly a local privilege escalation to get local root if appropriate, then you can just read the keys out of /proc/mem.

Don't forget the possibilities of side channel attacks using the electrical interface right down at the hardware level either, sometimes you can get crypto to leak bits of key data over this channel. Far too many security proofs ignore the fact that they apply to systems running on real electronics with real interfaces, not some abstract machine.

Also, if I have physical access it is game over, pull the dram modules (Possibly after spraying them with freezer spray) and just read out the keys, use JTAG, whatever, many possible attacks.

Comment: Tx Rx should connect to UART.   DR?

Comment: *Physical access it is game over* - well, secure modules like SIMs are available, but it does require special design.

Answer (score 4):

No.

First: The architecture you've shown in your diagram is grossly inaccurate. The UART in an ARM system, like the Raspberry Pi, is not connected directly to memory. It is typically connected to a peripheral bus (e.g, APB1 or APB2), which is separate from the memory bus.

Second:

> I could easily demo direct root shell if I open the serial UART connection and connect with minicom, then I got a root shell without a password with "the humble shell" hush on busybox/barebox using uClinux.

This behavior is mediated by the software running on the CPU. It has absolutely nothing to do with the hardware architecture, or the UART itself, and can be disabled by changing a configuration file.

Comment: The policy has "nothing" to do with the mechanism - please understand that a policy can't be hardware and that there must be some software (driver) to enforce a security policy.

Comment: @DjDac Then look at it this way: the "policy" you have effectively configured your system with is that the UART is hooked up to a root shell. _This is not inherent to the hardware._ It can be reconfigured to a normal username/password login, or another application, or disabled entirely.

Comment: You say it can be done. The repo has 5 million files. The FPGA design declares only one timer and uClinux needs two timers if I don't find a prior version that requires only one timer. And then we have the combinatorical explosion of kernel configurations and the combinatorical explosion of possible build errors. Sure it can be done if I only had that experience of embedded FPGA and then model it formally using NuSMV. Yes we can....

Answer (score 0):

> Do you agree that my illustration is "good enough" ?

Yes. it is an accurate depiction of a mcu that accesses its peripherals via DMA exclusively.